# Terraform index count

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm new to Terraform and practicing creating my first terraform. I've come across an error I'm uncertain of and reviewing same errors online it's not clear what it is I am expected to do. It feels like there's a fundamental "type" issue here. Can someone highlight what needs to be done and why.

Error:

```
 terraform validate
╷
│ Error: Missing resource instance key
│
│   on variables.tf line 32, in output "public_ip":
│   32:   value       = aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm.public_ip
│
│ Because aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm[count.index]
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing resource instance key
│
│   on variables.tf line 37, in output "instance_id":
│   37:   value       = aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm.id
│
│ Because aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm[count.index]
╵
```

`main.tf`

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = var.aws_access_key_id
  secret_key = var.aws_secret_access_key
  region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "my_rhel9_vm" {
  ami           = var.ami //RHEL 9 AMI
  instance_type = var.type
  count         = var.number_of_instances
  key_name      = var.ami_key_pair_name

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name_tag}"
  }
}
```

`variables.tf`

```
variable "ami" {
  type        = string
  description = "RHEL 9 AMI ID in US-East-1"
  default     = "ami-05a5f6298acdb05b6"
}

variable "type" {
  type        = string
  description = "Instance Type"
  default     = "t2.micro"
}

variable "name_tag" {
  type        = string
  description = "Name of the EC2 instance"
  default     = "My EC2 RHEL 9 instance"
}

variable "number_of_instances" {
  type        = number
  description = "Number of instances to be created"
  default     = 1
}

variable "ami_key_pair_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "SSH Key Pair"
  default     = "tomcat"
}

output "public_ip" {
  value       = aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm.public_ip
  description = "Public IP Address of EC2 instance"
}

output "instance_id" {
  value       = aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm.id
  description = "Instance ID"
}

variable "aws_access_key_id" {}
variable "aws_secret_access_key" {}

#locals {
# ami      = "ami-05a5f6298acdb05b6"
# type     = "t2.micro"
# name_tag = "My EC2 RHEL 9 instance"
#}
```

Comment: The answer depends on what your desired output value will be. Is it the IP for one of the instances, multiple instances, all of the instances, and if more than one instance, then what type of collection with what structure do you want it to be?

Comment: You have `var.ami.key_pair_name` but `var.ami` is a string (defined in the `variable "ami"`). You should first of all correct that.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. This is a setup I'm running on my laptop at home for learning. I set "number_of_instances" variable to 1 so should only spin up one instance I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that since `aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm` has a [`count`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count#basic-syntax) attribute, there can be multiple instances, so you need to specify which instance you are referring to. Basically, Terraform expects `aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm` to be an array of resources and you can refer to ech of them using an index like `aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm[0]`, `aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm[1]`, etc.

You could change `aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm` to `aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm[0]` in `variables.tf` to get a valid configuration

```
output "public_ip" {
  value       = aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm[0].public_ip
  description = "Public IP Address of EC2 instance"
}

output "instance_id" {
  value       = aws_instance.my_rhel9_vm[0].id
  description = "Instance ID"
}
```

From the [Terraform docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count#referring-to-instances):

> *When `count` is set, Terraform distinguishes between the block itself and the multiple resource or module instances associated with it. Instances are identified by an index number, starting with 0.*

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful. Why does this `[...]` only impact output variables and not input "variables"?

Comment: @Dan you aren't referencing a list of Terraform created resources in input variables (and indeed, it doesn't even make sense to do that), so the issue that you are encountering (referencing a single resource from a list of created resources) does not apply to your input variables.